# Unable to resolve module 'react-navigation'

Tags: react-native

Here is the error I get:

[image: Error]

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "LoginApp2",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
    "react-native": "0.48.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "21.2.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "21.2.1",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.0.0-alpha.12"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

**index.js**

```
  import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry,View,Text,StyleSheet } from 'react-native';

import UsersManager from './pages/app';
AppRegistry.registerComponent('LoginApp2', () => UsersManager);
```

**pages/app.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry,View,Text,StyleSheet,ScrollView,TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';

import HomeScreen from './home';
import Login from './login';
import Register from './register';
import Profile from './profile';

const UsersManager = StackNavigator({
Home: { screen: HomeScreen },
Login: { screen: Login },
Register: {screen: Register},
Profile: {screen: Profile}

});
export default UsersManager;
```

Can someone please help me solve this issue?

Comment: Make sure that you have installed 'react-navigation' on your project.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

This error means that either you haven't installed the `react-navigation` module or that you have installed the module but didn't re-built your project using `react-native run-android` or `react-native run-ios`.

---

**Following these steps should solve your issue:**

1. Install `react-navigation` module.
2. Re-build your project.
3. Restart the packager by stopping the current packager and then
   starting the packager again with `react-native start`.

Comment: The error still occure . Nothing changed.i installed react navigation module globally and  not inside the project.Rebuild the project by react-native run-android ? i did it also

Comment: You need to install the react-navigation in your project instead of globally installing it. Run npm install react-navigation --save inside your project folder.

Comment: Sorry but nothing changed same error.Even i created new project and installed react-navigation module

Comment: This error only comes if the packager doesn't get the desired module in the node modules. Just follow the steps in sequence i.e. Install react navigation in your project , then build your project using react-native run-android and restart your packager by stopping the current packager and starting again using react-native start and reload your application by pressing the reload button or by pressing double r.

Answer (score 15):

We need to install the following dependencies:

```
npm i react-navigation @react-native-community/masked-view react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-safe-area-context react-native-screens
```

In code import the following:

```
import {createAppContainer} from 'react-navigation'; 
import {createStackNavigator} from 'react-navigation-stack';
```

Answer (score 9):

**Date : 25-June-2020 Working :**

**Follow this steps:**

1. Install React Navigation
   npm install react-navigation
2. Install Dependencies
   expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
3. Install React Navigation Stack
   npm install react-navigation-stack @react-native-community/masked-view
4. Start the app and clear cache with
   npm start -c

Answer (score 4):

You have to just install the missing module ex.

```
npm install react-navigation
```

Then restart with

```
npm start
```

Answer (score 4):

**You can use this way**

- `npm install @react-navigation/native @react-navigation/native-stack`
- `expo install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context` // Expo
- `npm install react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context` // react native

```
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

<NavigationContainer>
    <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={ routeName } screenOptions = {{ headerShown: false }}>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component = { componentName } />
        <Stack.Screen name="Onboarding" component = { componentName } />
    </Stack.Navigator>
</NavigationContainer>
```

you can flow [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/navigation) document

Answer (score 3):

I just started to learn react. And got this problem, tried everything from the internet - nothing worked. Using Yarn instead of npm helped!

Comment: yarn add @react-navigation/native
worked for me as well

Answer (score 3):

run   "npm add @react-navigation/native"    :that saved me hours

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

`install` has been replaced with `add` to add new dependencies. Run `yarn add react-navigation` instead.

Answer (score 1):

This error happened after **updating to the new version**, to fix it, just run the following command

```
npx react-native start --reset-cache
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolve this error reading the react navigation documentation, execute `yarn add @react-navigation/native-stack`. Then the react navigation will be work

Answer (score 0):

**Install React Navigation**

```
npm install react-navigation --legacy-peer-deps
```

or

```
yarn add react-navigation
```

**Install Dependencies**

```
expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

**Install React Navigation Stack**

```
npm install react-navigation-stack @react-native-community/masked-view --legacy-peer-deps
```

or

```
yarn add react-navigation-stack @react-native-community/masked-view
```

Start the app and clear cache with `expo r -c`

Answer (score 0):

You need to install stack-navigator **in your project**.

1. npm install @react-navigation/stack
   and
2. npm install react-native-gesture-handler

2nd is also required, as per [reactnavigation.org](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/)

You can also follow this link for detailed steps:
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/

[Refer this image as well](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pume4.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Expo, run:

expo start -c
If you're not using Expo, run:

npx react-native start --reset-cache
If that doesn't work, you can also try the following:

rm -rf $TMPDIR/metro-bundler-cache-*

More information  [enter link description here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/troubleshooting/)

Answer (score 0):

Stop the server and run:

```bash
npm start
```

This will resolve the issue.