# Error: Unable to resolve module react-navigation-stack from /src/navigation/index.js:

Tags: react-native

I'm a react-native beginner.

I was doing stack screen. Then I've got the below error.

```
 Error: Unable to resolve module react-navigation-stack from /Users/chosohee/app2/src/navigation/index.js: react-navigation-stack could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
  ../node_modules
  1 | import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
> 2 | import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
    |                                       ^
  3 | import LoginScreen from './LoginScreen';
  4 | import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';
  5 |
    at ModuleResolver.resolveDependency (/Users/chosohee/app2/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph/ModuleResolution.js:178:15)
    at DependencyGraph.resolveDependency (/Users/chosohee/app2/node_modules/metro/src/node-haste/DependencyGraph.js:264:43)
    at Object.resolve (/Users/chosohee/app2/node_modules/metro/src/lib/transformHelpers.js:170:21)
    at resolveDependencies (/Users/chosohee/app2/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/graphOperations.js:466:33)
    at processModule (/Users/chosohee/app2/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/graphOperations.js:232:31)
    at async addDependency (/Users/chosohee/app2/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/graphOperations.js:361:18)
    at async Promise.all (index 7)
    at async processModule (/Users/chosohee/app2/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/graphOperations.js:279:3)
    at async addDependency (/Users/chosohee/app2/node_modules/metro/src/DeltaBundler/graphOperations.js:361:18)
    at async Promise.all (index 7)
```

Here is my src/navigation/index.js

```
import { createAppContainer, createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import LoginScreen from './LoginScreen';
import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';

const AuthStack = createStackNavigator(
    {
        LoginScreen: {screen: LoginScreen},
        HomesScreen: {screen: HomeScreen}
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'LoginScreen'
    }
);

const AppNavigator = createSwitchNavigator(
    {
        Auth: AuthStack
    },
    {
        initialRouteName: 'Auth',
    }
);

export default createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
```

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "app2",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "0.1.11",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "6.5.2",
    "@react-navigation/native": "6.1.1",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "6.9.7",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "6.3.10",
    "react": "18.1.0",
    "react-native": "0.70.6",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.8.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "2.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.4.1",
    "react-native-screens": "3.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.72.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.1.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I tried
[Unable to resolve module 'react-navigation'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47737609/unable-to-resolve-module-react-navigation)
https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/issues/9976
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/troubleshooting/

when I tried
npx react-native start --reset-cache

I got another error below.

```
error listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8081.
Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::8081
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (node:net:1717:16)
    at listenInCluster (node:net:1765:12)
    at Server.listen (node:net:1853:7)
    at /Users/chosohee/app2/node_modules/metro/src/index.flow.js:398:14
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at earlyPortCheck (/Users/chosohee/app2/node_modules/metro/src/index.flow.js:394:11)
    at exports.runServer (/Users/chosohee/app2/node_modules/metro/src/index.flow.js:155:9)
    at Object.runServer [as func] (/Users/chosohee/app2/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro/build/commands/start/runServer.js:123:49)
    at async Command.handleAction (/Users/chosohee/app2/node_modules/@react-native-community/cli/build/index.js:142:9)
info Run CLI with --verbose flag for more details.
```

Comment: did you import "import 'react-native-gesture-handler';" in index.js?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your import is not correct according to the stack navigation documentation you need to import `createStackNavigator` from `@react-navigation/stack` not from `react-navigation-stack` like this:

```
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
```

For more information you can check the documentation from [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/).

Comment: But,, I've got another error. Error: Unable to resolve module react-navigation from /Users/chosohee/app2/src/common/NavigationService.js: react-navigation could not be found within the project or in these directories:
  node_modules
  ../node_modules
> 1 | import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';
    |                                    ^

Comment: NavigationService.js// import { NavigationActions } from 'react-navigation';

let _navigator;

function setTopLevelNavigator(navigatorRef) {
    _navigator = navigatorRef;
}

function navigate(routeName, params) {
    _navigator.dispatch(
        NavigationActions.navigate({
            routeName,
            params,
        })
    )
    
}

function back() { 
    _navigator.dispatch(
        NavigationActions.back()
    );
}

// add other navigation functions that you need and export them

export default {
    navigate,
    setTopLevelNavigator,
    back,
};

Comment: react-navigation only for React Navigation 4.x, which is no longer actively maintained. https://reactnavigation.org/docs/4.x/navigation-actions/

you need to check latest version :
https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-actions